# No eslint warning when ref is missing in useEffect dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref, use-effect

I have one doubt about `ref` in `useEffect`.
Do I need to add it to dependency?

```
const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    //do something about ref
  }, []); //<-- ref is not here
}
```

the above code doesn't give any eslint warning. is `ref` exempted in the dependency?

Comment: `ref` itself is referentially stable, the value it points to `ref.current` is what changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you don't have to add `ref` to the dependencies array.

For deeper understanding you can read [A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect) by Dan Abramov. A quote from there, that answers your question:

> (You may omit dispatch, setState, and useRef container values from the deps because React guarantees them to be static. But it also doesn’t hurt to specify them.)